# Refreshing iOS Provision Profile after Certificate is Approved

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I enrolled as an iOS Developer under a team membership (ios university program).
I requested a certificate they approved.

So I click refresh button in my provision profile but it gives an error saying The selected team does not have a program membership that is eligible for this feature.

As you see there is a green light next to my iPhone device. My team admin coudlnt find why this issue occurs.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

I have the Xcode 4.4, iPhone 5.1.1.

[image]

Comment: same issue for me...this is really annoying

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with Xcode 4.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Download the developer profile and certificates from https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action -> but at the moment (10-29-12) the developer portal is not available -> maintanience in progress.